# Array of Mondays

Tags: ember.js

I am a JS/Ember noob, so please be patient. My app has a program model that has a start and end date. I want to add a function/computed property that will return an array of all the weeks covering the program.

The basic psuedocode would be something like:

```
weeks: Ember.computed, ->
  monday_array = []

  if start_date.day_of_week != monday
    monday = find monday before start date
  else 
    monday = start_date
  end

  while monday < end_date
    push monday onto monday_array
```

I am not really sure where to start on this and have not found the ember api or other online resources to help me much. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If it matters I am using coffescript

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different that what was originally described but it is the same idea

```
  weeks: Ember.computed 'starts_at', 'ends_at' , ->
    arr = []
    current_monday = @getMonday(@get('starts_at'))
    if Date(@getMonday(@get('ends_at'))) > new Date(Date.today.getDate() + 7)
      end_monday = new Date(@getMonday(@get('ends_at')))
    else
      end_monday = new Date(@getMonday(Date.today.getDate + 21))

    while current_monday <= end_monday
      newDate = current_monday.setDate(current_monday.getDate() + 7)
      current_monday = new Date(newDate)
      arr.push(current_monday)
    return arr

  getMonday: (d) ->
    d = new Date(d)
    day = d.getDay()
    diff = d.getDate() - day + ((if day is 0 then -6 else 1)) # adjust when day is sunday
    new Date(d.setDate(diff))
```